# Name of a particular probability distribution

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, reference-request, terminology

Suppose the probability mass function $\{p_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ takes the form
\begin{equation}\label{eq:p*n_example}
p_n = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
     n\,p_0\,r^n, & \quad \text{if}~ n \geq 1,\\
     p_0, &\quad \text{if}~ n = 0
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{equation}
for some $0 < r < 1$. May I know is there any "standard name" for such (discrete) probability distribution?

Comment: Geometric distribution. You can write it as $p_n = r(1 - r)^n $, for $n = 0, 1, 2, ...$

Comment: Hello, you clearly forgot the factor $n$ in front of the $p_n\,r^n$  term

Comment: Sorry, long day xD So it looks like kind of modified geometric distribution anyway.

Comment: Of course I know this distribution is some sort of modification of the famous geometric distribution, that's why I am asking if there is any "standard name" to which I can refer this distribution...

Comment: Shifted geometric distribution?

Comment: Hello, I disagree. I am asking if there is any "standard name" for that...

Comment: Maybe a specific zero-inflated ${}_1F_0$ distribution, though I doubt there’s anything standard about that.

Answer (score 1):

This distribution does not have a special name but it can be related back to known distributions.

Let $Z\sim\operatorname{Bernoulli}(p_1)$ with
$$
p_1=\frac{\frac{r}{(1-r)^2}}{1+\frac{r}{(1-r)^2}}
$$
and $X\sim\operatorname{NegativeBinomial}(2,1-r)$ be independent Bernoulli and negative binomial random variables. Now define
$$
W=Z(X+1).
$$
Now notice that
$$
\mathsf P(W=0)=\mathsf P(Z=0)=1-p_1=\frac{1}{1+\frac{r}{(1-r)^2}}.
$$
Likewise, for $n=1,2,\dots$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathsf P(W=n)
&=\mathsf P(Z=1\cap X=n-1)\\
&=\mathsf P(Z=1)\mathsf P(X+1=n)\\
&=\frac{\frac{r}{(1-r)^2}}{1+\frac{r}{(1-r)^2}}nr^n.
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus
$$
\mathsf P(W=n)=
\begin{cases}
1-p_1, &n=0\\
p_1nr^n, &n\geq 1,
\end{cases}
$$
which is the distribution in question.

Comment: Ok, so this distribution car arise from a product random variable.... But still, maybe there is no "standard name" for such a distribution... Also I believe your computation is problematic. For instance, for $n = 4$ the probability $\mathbb{P}(W = 4)$ should contain the term $\mathbb{P}(Z =2)\cdot \mathbb{P}(X = 1)$ as well.

Comment: Not quite.  $P(W=4)=P(Z=1)P(X+1=4)$ since $Z$ can only take on values of zero and one.

Comment: @MathandYuGiOhlover In this case, the distributiondoesn't have it's own name but it can be related back to distributions with known names.